# Cant able to install the latest npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

My current version of npm is

> 5.6.0

When I tried

> npm install -g npm@latest

getting the below error

> npm ERR! code ENOSELF
>   Refusing to install package with name "npm" under a package
>   also called "npm". Did you name your project the same
>   as the dependency you're installing?
>
> For more information, see:
>       https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Is your project name is "npm"?

Comment: delete old one and reinstall it.

Comment: @thangavel.R I used the command prompt for install the npm locally not by project specified

Comment: Is already any other node modules in your project path? if yes then delete it and install it.

Comment: npm install -g npm@next try this

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan Are you trying to update the whole npm or just the packages for your project?

Comment: @TheParam when using the command the same error ocurred

Comment: @Arcteezy Whole npm

Comment: @ArunKumar i am not trying for a project I am trying for whole npm

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan Try `npm update -g`

Comment: @Arcteezy It is completed without error. then I tried to find out the version it is still the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

At last it is fixed.

First delete the npm and npm-cache folder from the **%user_profile%appdata/Roaming** . Then run the install latest npm command:

> npm install npm@latest -g

Now the version is updated to latest one.